# Efficient Lookup Table

Tags: excel, lookup-tables, vba

I currently have a look up table i am using to assign a value to a record given 3 inputs to match before a value is assigned.  The table has 3426 records and I am looking to find a way to make the lookup procedure run quicker.  I am using the following function to perform the look up:

```
Function FindValue(rng1 As String, rng2 As Date, rng3 As String) As Variant
Dim varVal1 As Variant
Dim varVal2 As Variant
Dim varVal3 As Variant
Dim rngTargetA As Range
Dim rngTargetB As Range
Dim rngTargetC As Range
Dim lngRowCounter As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

varVal1 = rng1
varVal2 = rng2
varVal3 = rng3

Set ws = Sheets("Uncertinaty_LU")
lngRowCounter = 2
Set rngTargetA = ws.Range("A" & lngRowCounter)
Set rngTargetB = ws.Range("B" & lngRowCounter)
Set rngTargetC = ws.Range("C" & lngRowCounter)
Do While Not IsEmpty(rngTargetA.Value)
    If UCase(rngTargetA.Value) = varVal1 And rngTargetB.Value = varVal2 And UCase(rngTargetC.Value) = UCase(varVal3) Then
        FindValue = ws.Range("D" & lngRowCounter).Value
        Exit Function
    End If

    lngRowCounter = lngRowCounter + 1
    Set rngTargetA = ws.Range("A" & lngRowCounter)
    Set rngTargetB = ws.Range("B" & lngRowCounter)
    Set rngTargetC = ws.Range("C" & lngRowCounter)
Loop

' if we don't find anything, return an empty string '

MsgBox ("Could not find uncertainty value for " & varVal1 & ", " & varVal2 & ", " & varVal3)
FindValue = ""


End Function
```

In the above function `rng1`,`rng2`, and `rng3` are input puts from another page in the workbook.

Although there are 3426 records in the look up table, there are 38 unique values in `rngTargetA` and 4 unique values for `rngTargetC`.  I am looking to find a solution where it first locates the unique value of interest in `rngTargetA` before it begins looping through records to find the record of interest.

Comment: what is the other page in the workbook that  rng1,2,3 are referencing?

Comment: Why not just place a temporary autofilter on your lookup table, filter for the relevant inputs and then read the value?

Comment: I thought about that too, but i am reluctant to use built in excel functions to subset the lookup table.  Its almost like i want to commit the lookup table to memory instead of reading it line by line each time the function is called.

Comment: @PJRosenburg rng1,2,3 are referencing 3 cells on other worksheets in the workbook.  More specifically they come from a text file i read and input into cells.  This function is called anywhere from 40 to 100 times in a worksheet.  In total i have 84 sheets that use this function.